# Static var, method or singleton?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

i was wondering how to access "static" vars from a model from different ViewControllers.
Should I go for:

- static vars (if yes, how?)
- static method
- singleton + method
- singleton + variable (custom getters)

---

```
#import "CategoryModel.h"

@implementation CategoryModel

-(NSArray*) allSelected {
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SELECTEDCATEGORIES_DEFAULTSKEY]];
}

-(NSString*) allSelectedAsUrlParams {
    NSMutableString *categoryList = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSArray *category in self.allSelected) {
        [categoryList appendString:[category valueForKey:@"value"]];
        if(![[self.allSelected lastObject] isEqual:category]) {
            [categoryList appendString:@","];
        }
    }

    return categoryList;

}

@end
```

---

**Edit (working) **

```
// header
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CategoryModel : NSObject

+ (NSString*)allSelectedAsUrlParams;

@end


// implementation
#import "CategoryModel.h"

@implementation CategoryModel


+ (NSString*)allSelectedAsUrlParams {
    return @"somethingGreat";
}

@end

// How to use
CategoryModel.allSelectedAsUrlParams
```

Comment: I've posted the working code

Answer (score 1):

This is really going to be a matter of architectural preference, but if more than one class is going to need the static vars, this is one approach:

```
Constants.h

extern BOOL const TEST_MODE;
extern NSString * const SOME_STRING;

Constants.m

BOOL const TEST_MODE = YES;
NSString * const SOME_STRING = @"SomeString";
```

As an alternative, you can just add the `extern NSString * const SOME_STRING;` to the header of class that it is specific to (and the corresponding `NSString * const SOME_STRING = @"SomeString";` in the .m) and then call that var directly by importing the header of the class with the constant you need and using `SOME_STRING` to get at it.

Comment: `ClassName.SOME_STRING` might work in other languages, but not in Objective-C. As long as you've imported the header, it's just `SOME_STRING`.

Comment: Indeed... My mind is bouncing back and forth between some Obj-C and C# projects. I edited the answer to reflect your comment :)

Comment: Oof, that's gotta be hard. :-)

Comment: Thanks but SOME_STRING (instead of Category.something) is not a good choice for me. This is not about global const but about a simple model i need in different VCs. Maybe I should try to go for static methods instead?